# Deploying changes to an app hosted on Heroku without using Git

Tags: git, github, heroku

I have an application on GitHub that is deployed to Heroku. Even if I'm at a computer where Git is not installed, I can make changes to the files in the repository via the GitHub website. However, I'm not sure if I can deploy those changes to Heroku without invoking "git push heroku". Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not possible - deploys must be via git push

Answer (score 10):

This is possible now, check out https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push

Answer (score 0):

If you can get access to shell account somewhere with Git installed you could do it that way. Then all you'd need would be an SSH client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this new Heroku plugin:

```
$ heroku plugins:install https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push
$ heroku push ~/myapp
```